# Install RStudio on Kubuntu

Tags: r, rstudio

How do I install R Studio on Kubuntu? Not Ubuntu (there is a slight difference in installation process).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I've found to install RStudio on Kubuntu (16.04 currently) is by downloading RStudio .deb file, first.

Open a terminal:

1. `sudo dpkg -i rstudio-0.99.903-amd64.deb` (or whatever version you downloaded)
2. If that fails, which it has always done for me, you'll need to install dependencies libjpeg62, libgstreamer0.10-0, libstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0. Try:
   `sudo apt-get install libjpeg62`
3. You'll probably be prompted with something like:

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   rstudio : Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: r-base (>= 2.11.1) but it is not going to be installed
   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
   ```
4. Go ahead and try: `apt-get -f install` and the dependencies should be installed.

'This command does the same thing as Edit->Fix Broken Packages in Synaptic. Do this if you get complaints about packages with "unmet dependencies"'. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

5. Try again: `sudo dpkg -i apt-get install rstudio-0.99.903-amd64.deb` and RStudio should install just fine.

Any questions or comments to improve this process will be appreciated.

Thanks